# Book from Cold War era where USSR defeats USA by sabotaging food supply

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book about 25 years ago. It was in Polish, titled "Głód" (which means "hunger").

I remember that it involved various ways some US food stocks were sabotaged (both products on store shelves and in various food processing plants) — for example some canned meat was poisoned with (possibly) botulinum, causing the US government to issue a warning to Americans to avoid canned food altogether.

I also remember there was a US senator who was on some sort of a committee that had sole authority to release strategic food reserves for distribution to the population, but at the same time the "attacks" happened was incommunicado with his assistant/mistress, who at the end reveals herself to be Soviet spy.

I don't remember the original title nor the author (though I have the feeling it was a big name, maybe Stephen King). And when I was reading it about 25 years ago it had been out for quite a few years.

Comment: "Cold War Era"? You mean Cold War I, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is *[Famine](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1835585.Famine)* by Graham Masterton.

> A nationwide famine has swept across America. Ed Hardesty, a wheat farmer, attempts to find out the source of the blight which has devastated the world.

The contamination appears to be a mix of botulism and radioactive isotopes

> *In a special newsflash on Wednesday evening, at nine o’clock Central
> Time, the President of the United States confirmed that ‘all food
> produce containing cereals — and that includes processed meats,
> breads, cookies, pastas, beers, and spirits – must now come under
> suspicion of having been contaminated with heavy cobalt radiation. As
> a general rule, foodstuffs produced more than three weeks ago can be
> considered safe – provided, of course, they are canned, or frozen, or
> still fresh. But if you are in doubt, a more detailed explanation will
> be broadcast immediately after this message on your local television
> station, and on your local radio. You will also be able to obtain
> leaflets from your City Hall or local citizens’ centre.’*

and

> *The Secretary of Health concluded that ‘it must be beyond serious doubt that some malevolent agency has deliberately and in a calculated manner introduced Clostridium botulinum into a random variety of canned foods throughout the nation. Therefore – as grave as I realise the implications of such a recommendation must be – I have to put forward the urgent suggestion that the sale of all canned foods in the United States be immediately suspended pending more detailed investigation.’*

Comment: Cool, it has reviews in Polish.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Thank you!!!      Also... somewhat on topic in these days, isn't it?